# How to get beacon major and minor id in didExitRegion

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ibeacon

I have created a iphone app for beacons. In that i want to display the message when i am exit from all the beacons region.

1. I dont want to display the message for every beacon exit region. For example, If have 3 beacons, I want to display the message only when i am exit of all the 3 beacons. Is it possible to do that?
2. And also i want to get the exiting beacon major and minor values in `didExitRegion`

I used the following code:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
   didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons
          inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
// Beacon found!
NSLog(@"iBeacons found");
//    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Successfully found" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; [alert show];

CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

// You can retrieve the beacon data from its properties
NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
NSString *majorId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
NSString *minorId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];
NSLog(@"UUID: %@", uuid);
}
```

In the above code i can get the uuid, major, minor of the beacons. But I want to get the values of the exiting beacon in `didExitRegion`. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mutable array to keep track of the region details of the detected beacon. And update that array with detection of new beacon regions. Like the code below

In delegate method `didDetermineState` add

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if(state == CLRegionStateInside)
    {
        [regions addObject:region]; // regions is the mutable array 
    }
}
```

And with `didExitRegion` method add

```
// Tells the delegate that the user left the specified region. 
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
    {
        [regions removeObject:region];
        CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        NSLog(@"\nExited region id: %@",beaconRegion.identifier);
        NSLog(@"\nExited region major: %@",beaconRegion.major);
        NSLog(@"\nExited region minor: %@",beaconRegion.minor);

       // Add a check with regions array here to show the custom alert message

    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, I do get the UID , But major and minor values as null. Any help would be greatful :)

Answer (score 0):

> I dont want to display the message for every beacon exit region. For
>   example, If have 3 beacons, I want to display the message only when i
>   am exit of all the 3 beacons. Is it possible to do that?

Your requirements don't seem completely clear. If these three beacons are described by a single region you're monitoring, then it's simple: you will only get a single `didExitRegion:` message as you leave the range of the last beacon in the region. Otherwise, Alex's suggestion above seems reasonable: track regions you're entering and exiting, then conditionally execute some code in `didExitRegion:` when the count of regions you're currently in drops to zero.

> And also i want to get the exiting beacon major and minor values in
>   `didExitRegion`

I'm not sure "exiting beacon" is well-defined here (do you mean, say, the last beacon in the region whose range you left, hence triggering the `didExitRegion:` message?), but in any case you can't get what you're asking for here. Where Alex logs `major` and `minor`, they are attributes of the *region* being monitored (and, in this case, being exited), not of any specific *beacon*.